# close existing opened window inside XMLHttpRequest handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Currently I'm using Javascript with Ajax to fetch some data and present it in a new window.  I'm trying to close the window in OpenFileWindow() before a new one is opened, but while the it finds the window object, all properties and methods give a permission denied error.

I'm believe it has to do with scoping with the Ajax call as when I open the window before XMLHttpRequest, there's no problem.

I'm not sure how to proceed and I've searched quite a bit. Anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks.

opened

```
var newWin = null;
function View_onClick(propId, url) {
    var param = "propId=" + propId;
    param += "&filename=" + url;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "GetActivityFileName.ashx", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                if (xhr.responseText == "") {
                    alert("Sorry unable to find file.");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    OpenFileWindow(xhr.responseText)
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(param);
    return false;
}


function OpenFileWindow(fileUrl) {
        if(newWin != null)
            newWin.close();
        newWin = window.open(fileUrl);
        newWin.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to just re-use the window, why not name it.

If you give the same name as the 2nd parameter of `window.open,` it will re-use that window.

Comment: Actually I tried this, I used the second name parameter for window.open but it still keeps opening new windows.  I believe it's a scoping issue as when I open a URL before the Ajax call, then that works.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  If the window is still open, change the URL.  Otherwise, open the window and load the URL.

```
function OpenFileWindow(fileUrl) {
        if(newWin == null || newWin.closed) 
          newWin = window.open(fileUrl);
        else
          newWin.location.replace(fileUrl);

        newWin.focus();
}
```

Comment: newWin.location.replace(fileUrl) still gives permission denied.

Comment: Is fileURL on a different domain?

Comment: Yeah it's on a different domain. This is something I'd have to definitely check out as previous code without XMLHttpRequest is working and it allowed closing of the window.